# Show advanced search form outside fieldset

Tags: 7, hooks, search, forms

When I search for a keyword in core Drupal search, it shows a results page with a link named *Advanced search* that hides a fieldset with more form options. I want it to be shown in the basic search form, not only on search result page, and it should be expanded by default.

Note: I want all this with core search in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [Advanced Search Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search):

> This module alters the default search box in many ways. If you need to
> have options available like in advanced search, but directly in the
> search box, this module is for you.
>
> Basic options The module adds
> options to select:
>
> which content type(s) to search, which specific module search to use
> (node, help, user or any module that implements search), which input
> type to use (with Elements), advanced criteria For all these choices,
> there are options to switch between a select box, checkboxes or radio
> buttons, and also customize the selector label and the default - Any -
> text.
>
> Advanced options There are also options to:
>
> change the default search box label, add a default text in the search
> box, add advanced search criteria, change the default submit button
> text, use an image instead of the submit button, change the order of
> all the elements, include some elements in a popup block, add a filter
> to the results page, show/hide basic and/or advanced search in the
> results page, show/hide meta data in the results page, multiple search
> paths

Comment: I have checked this module. Although it provides good customization but here it does not give full solution of my problem. As I said in my question that I want to show advance search form with basic search form either user submit a form or not.